# Access domain A while authenticated against domain B

Tags: authentication, wifi, domain

In my school, there are 2 domains; **A** (primary) and **B** (secondary).

- **A** contains the resources required by staff and students.
- Connecting to the wireless network requires authentication with an account under **B**.
- The school has acquired several Win8 tablets and wants them accessing **A**, via the wireless (they have no ethernet connection).
- I don't have access to configure either domain as they are managed externally (I'd rather sort this out myself if possible before I contact them, as I won't learn anything if they fix it), but I do have access to join a machine to the domain.

Is this possible? I have tried joining the machines to domain **A** but cannot.

Answer (score 1):

You need a trust between the two domains, and then you could make that scenario work.